# How to specify additional props in a styled component in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a styled component defined by `withStyles` from `material-ui`. I am using `typescript` so it complains about type error on the last line. The reason is that the component `ServiceListComponent` requires `classes` and `services` but `withStyles` only provides `classes`. The `services` will be provided from parent component. How can I make the type correct in `withStyle` statement?

```
const styles = createStyles({...})
interface Props {
  services: RootState.ServicesState;
  classes: { [className in keyof typeof styles]: string };
}

const ServiceListComponent = ({ classes, services }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.parent} spacing={8}>
        {itemsArray.map(value => (
          <Grid key={value} item className={classes.item} xs={4} sm={4} md={3} xl={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

ServiceListComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export const ServiceList = withStyles(styles)(ServiceListComponent);
```

The error for above code is in the last line:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ ({ classes, services }: Props): Element; propTypes: { classes: Validator<object>; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<ConsistentWith<Props, { classes: Record<"root" | "parent" | "paper" | "items" | "item", string>; }>>'.
  Type '{ ({ classes, services }: Props): Element; propTypes: { classes: Validator<object>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<ConsistentWith<Props, { classes: Record<"root" | "parent" | "paper" | "items" | "item", string>; }>>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type '{ classes: Validator<object>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ConsistentWith<Props, { classes: Record<"root" | "parent" | "paper" | "items" | "item", string>; }>>'.
        Types of property 'classes' are incompatible.
          Type 'Validator<object>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<{ root: string; parent: string; paper: string; items: string; item: string; }>'.
            Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ root: string; parent: string; paper: string; items: string; item: string; }': root, parent, paper, items, item
```

I can make it correct by adding `any` as below but I don't want to use any.

```
export const ServiceList = withStyles(styles)<any>(ServiceListComponent);
```